React native error with nativewind: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins
I'm new to Reactnative and just following a tutorial on youtube, but I'm getting this error
Android Bundling failed 187129ms C:\Users\user2\Desktop\Apps\test_app\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js (936 modules)
error: app\_layout.jsx: C:\Users\user2\Desktop\Apps\gimflo\app\_layout.jsx: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins

Here is my index.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Link } from 'expo-router';
import { styled } from 'nativewind';

const StyledView = styled(View);
const StyledText = styled(Text);
const StyledLink = styled(Link);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledView className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-white">
      <StyledText className="text-3xl">Hello World</StyledText>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <StyledLink href="/profile" className="text-blue-500">
        Go to Profile
      </StyledLink>
    </StyledView>
  );
}

Here is my _layout.jsx
import {Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { Slot, Stack } from 'expo-router';

const RootLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name='index' options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default RootLayout

Here is my babel.config.js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['nativewind/babel'],
  };
};

Everything worked until i tried native wind.
